# Default template in Code Blocks

Tags: codeblocks

I want to set a default template code in code blocks. How can I set a default code in code blocks which appears every time when I open a new project or empty file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create normally a new project and customize it with the code you want and then go to **`File` > `Save project as template`**. Now, whenever you want to use that template as the initial structure for your project, you go to **`File` > `New` > `From template...`** and choose it.

Comment: That will make a copy of the template but inside memory both file will point to same location. So when you modify new Project file created form file, It'll update default template code also. That's difficult to resolve. Please help with any solution if you have.

Answer (score 4):

For a default Template in codeblocks.

Goto

```
Settings > Editor > Default Code
```

Here select the type of file as C/C++ source file. Now paste your template into this and save it. From now on whenever you create a new C/C++ file this template loads by default.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **change default code of main.cpp** to your own default code —

- Go to Program Files/CodeBlocks/share/CodeBlocks/templates/wizard/console/cpp.
- Open file main.cpp, what you need is just to edit the content of this file to your default code and save it.

from next time you will get your default codes :)